# Calculate average across rows that match an ID and a word - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

**Table is as follows:**

[image]

I want calculate the average of values in column C for rows with value "ABC" in column A and value "Yes" in column B.

So, basically, the average of values 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
*(following [OP's request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/143248/calculate-average-across-rows-that-match-an-id-and-a-word-google-sheets#comment130808_143250))*

To completely skip any header (display nothing instead of `some words`) please use

```
=QUERY(A1:C4,"select avg(C) where A='ABC' and B='Yes' label avg(C) '' ")
```

Please notice the pair of single quotes in the end

---

You can use this query formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:C4,"select avg(C) where A='ABC' and B='Yes' label avg(C) 'Average if ABC/Yes' ")
```

[image]

More about [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thank you. Can it output only the avg value and not the "Average if ABC/Yes" label?

Comment: Please see the edited answer.Also, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!